# Auto clear textbox after barcode input and passing the value to a string

Tags: c#, barcode

this is my first time to use this barcode reader hardware. Im having a problem in auto clear the textbox after barcode input. It clears the textbox before it passes the value to a respective string.

```
private void txtStudentID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = txtStudentID.Text;
    sqlDisplayInfo = a;
    txtStudentID.Text.Clear()
}
```

I also tried using thread but it fails

```
private void txtStudentID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = txtStudentID.Text;
    sqlDisplayInfo = a;
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    txtStudentID.Text.Clear()
}
```

EDIT for my new code:

i have problem here +=. example i scanned a barcode then it combines the previous scan and the next scan

i use timer tick but it is not perfect as it is because sometimes it cause delay in retrieving the data in the database, so it does not collaborate with the time intervals

```
private void txtStudentID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = (700);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            a = txtStudentID.Text;
            displayData(a);//passing string a to method data retrieve
            timer2.Interval = (700);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer2.Start();
        }

        private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.txtStudentID.Text))
            {
                timer2.Stop();
                txtStudentID.Clear();
            }
        }
```

Comment: The issue is the barcode reader emulates someone typing, although very quickly. Therefore, my guess is that the TextChanged event fires for every single character scanned. You will need a way to determine when the string is done (special character perhaps that is hardcoded into the barcode reader?) then capture the string once you know the complete string is entered. Good Luck!

Comment: the txtStudentID.Text.Clear() action is most likely triggering the txtStudentID_TextChanged event to get triggered again. You will need to provide more information about your application to see if there is another way to achieve what you want.

Comment: that what i also think sir, the event fires for every 3 or 2 characters I guess but my barcode ID character length were 6. How do i do it? i also tried key up, key press, key down but nothing succeeds

Comment: @ sir kevin. i want to pass the value from txtStudentID to sqlDisplay which will trigger to display the information from sql database and the textbox will be cleared after passing those value and ready to read another input from the barcode.
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
barcode input to textbox--> pass the value to string---> clear the textbox after passing the value ----> accept another barcode input. This would be the cycle i wanted

Comment: When I did this, I actually created my own bar code scanner control (derived for text box) and fired a separate event when I detected a full string had been scanned. I believe I used special characters to delimit text. If you don't want to go this route, you can have a timing threshold that resets for each character scanned, then when it crosses that threshold (like 250 ms or something) then capture the whole string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to all for giving ideas.
Now i figure it out..

```
private void txtStudentID_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Interval = (700);
            timer1.Enabled = true;
            timer1.Start();
        }

        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timer1.Stop();
            a = txtStudentID.Text;
            displayData(a);// i put the txtStudentID.Clear() at the end of the method. I think i need some rest. :)
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess the issue is not the barcode reader but the fact that you are using text changed event. It's triggered when the reader provides the value to the text box (I assume that's how the textbox is populated). But it also triggers when you clear the textbox.

So what happens is:

1. Read value (for example "123"): Textbox gets populated. The variable `sqlDisplayInfo` is populated with "123".
2. Next line of the method clears the text box.
3. The textbox is empty (so the text did change). The `textChanged` event is triggered.
4. The textbox text is empty string. And so the same value is assigned to `sqlDisplayInfo`.

Hence you don't see any change in the value of `sqlDisplayInfo`. Try debugging your code then you can see that the event is triggered twice.

**EDIT:**

From your comment it looks like the barcode reader reads letter by letter. So ideally would be to have a signal that says the reading is done. You read the string, construct it in a temp variable, and when the signal is received you assign the value of the temp varialble to your `sqlDisplayInfo`, clear the variable and the Textbox.

Another option is probably just to read the text box and append it (not assign) to the `sqlDisplayInfo` variable.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(this.textBox1.Text))
    {
        sqlDisplayInfo += this.textBox1.Text;
    }

    this.textBox1.Clear();
}
```

You still trigger twice as much text changed events as necessary but only react when the text box changed after you read the value.

Comment: i tried your code sir but it only pass the last digit number of the barcode. the barcode number is 110005 and the only value will be pass is the 5.

Comment: Right. I thought your barcode reader consumes whole string at once. But it looks like it reads letter by letter. I'll adjust my answer

Comment: i have problem here +=. example i scanned a barcode then it also combine the previous scan and the next scan

Comment: Yes, I assume it combined the barcodes. The code is just a draft. a starting point. Obviously, you have to implement the whole solution, maybe add events to indicate the scanning is done. Or maybe clearing your variable before next scan, etc. What I was trying to do was rather to help you understand what's the source of your problem and where to start looking for some solution. I have far too little data on your system: how the scanning functions, what it sends in, etc. to provide a complete solution.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you !

```
    private void txtSearch_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                try
                {
                    if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Enter)
                    {
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtSearch.Text))
                        {
                            var itemKey = _blItems.GetItemKeyByBarcode(txtSearch.Text);
                            if (itemKey > 0)
                            {
                                var model = _blItems.GetItemDetailsDataTable(itemKey);
                                dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
                                dataGridView1.DataSource = model;
                            }
                            txtSearch.Clear();
                            txtSearch.Select();
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch { }
            }
```